# How do you make a custom filter?

Tags: haskell, filter

I am having trouble trying to figure this out myself with no success. I am trying to make my own Filter where instead of not including something in the List because it is false it does something.

#### The code

What I have tried:

```
myfilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
myfilter p (x:xs)
 | p x = x : myfilter p xs
 | otherwise = []:myfilter p xs
```

I was trying to make myFilter add a blank [ ] to the output list for example.

```
myFilter isIt1andOnly1[[1],[2,2],[3,4]]])
```

#### The output

What output should be:

```
[[1], [ ], [ ], []]
```

What the inbuilt filter does:

```
[[1]]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

#### EDIT:

Sorry for any misunderstandings I caused but I wasn't looking for

```
filter (==1) [list]
```

changed the question a bit to be a bit more specific on the issue of custom filter rather than filter (==1) [[randomlist]]

Comment: A solution would be using `map filter (==1)` this will yield the result given your input, and try to work your way back from there, best starting with the type signature

Comment: What is the expected result of `[[],[1],[1,1],[1,2]]`

Comment: Maybe I should reword my question I did it generally so its easier to understand I just want filter to do something if its false and something else if its true

Answer (score 3):

`myfilter` doesn't know that it's working with lists of lists. Look at the type signature you gave `myfilter`:

```
myfilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

`[a]` means "list of an arbitrary type `a`"; `myfilter` doesn't know anything about `a`. So in the `otherwise` branch, the type-checker thinks "you're trying to output an empty list, but I'm not certain that `a` is in fact a list".

One way to fix it would be to adjust the type signature to be more specific about the fact that we're working with nested lists:

```
myfilter :: ([a] -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

Another problem you're having with this code is that you've forgotten to handle the case when the input list is empty. You need to add a clause matching the empty list:

```
myfilter p [] = []
```

Answer (score 1):

`myfilter` is correct. Like `filter`, all it does is, well, *filter* a list: it passes on some elements and some not, but it never changes any of them.

Whereas you propose to have elements in the result that aren't in the original list. This can't be done with `filter`. However, there's another constant you have: you never change the *structure* of the (outer) list. So, this is a task for `map`. Where you do filter is on the *inner* lists, so you need to map the filtering over the outer list. Thanks to currying, this is extremely easy in Haskell:

```
Prelude> map (filter isItOne) [[1],[2],[3],[1]]
[[1],[],[],[1]]
```

Here, `isItOne` must have the signature `Integer -> Bool`: it only works on single *elements* of the inner list, not on the whole inner list. That's what you implemented anyway.

A couple of better ways to write `isItOne`:

```
iItOne :: Integer -> Bool

isItOne x | x == 1     = True
          | otherwise  = False

isItOne x = x==1

isItOne = (==1)
```

In fact, you might as well just inline this:

```
Prelude> map (filter (==1)) [[1],[2],[3],[1]]
[[1],[],[],[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

With those edits - I think the function should work a bit different, but first a solution to your problem

```
myfilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
myfilter _ []                   = [ ]
myfilter p ([x]:xs) | p x       = [x]: myfilter p xs
                    | otherwise = [ ]: myfilter p xs
myfilter p ( _ :xs)             = [ ]:myfilter p xs
```

But this is kind of clumsy to include the "logic" that you are looking for singleton lists in this function. I would rather write something like a `monoidalFilter` - which is a term I just invented. A monoid is something that allows for concatenation/addition/multiplication and has a neutral element think something like a zero or one.

```
monoidalFilter :: Monoid m :: (m -> Bool) -> [m] -> [m]
monoidalFilter p = map (\x -> if p x then x else mempty)
```

then `monoidalFilter (==[1])` would do the trick

```
> ghci tst.hs
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tst.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> monoidalFilter (==[1]) [[],[1],[1,1],[2,2]]
[[],[1],[],[]]
*Main> myfilter (==1) [[],[1],[1,1],[2,2]]
[[],[1],[],[]]
```